# Непонятные символы при вводе русских букв (кириллицы) в Java

Tags: java, scanner, netbeans

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner n = new Scanner (System.in);
     String fio;
     System.out.print("Введите Фамилию :");
     fio = n.nextLine();
     System.out.println(fio);
}
```

> Введите Фамилию: Иванов Денис Иванович
>   ������ ����� ��������
>   СБОРКА УСПЕШНО ЗАВЕРШЕНА (общее время: 19 секунд)

При вводе русских букв выводит непонятные символы. Как исправить? Подскажите, если можно, пример, работаю в NetBeans IDE 8.0.1.

Comment: В какой среде разработки запускаете код?

Comment: добрый день, в NetBeans IDE 8.0.1. Заранее благодарю

Answer (score 4):

Ваша проблема описана [тут](http://metanit.com/java/tutorial/2.9.php).

Если вы пишете в NetBeans, то вам необходимо зайти в свойства проекта и поменять кодировку на `windows-1251`.
После этого данный код работает корректно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Либо как вариант указать кодировку вводимых символов сразу:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in,"Cp1251"));
    System.out.println("Введите ФИО:");
    //Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = br.readLine();
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если пишешь в Netbeans -

Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in, "Cp866");

Без проблем будет читать
русские буквы.