# Не работает сравнение русских строк в Java

Tags: java, scanner

```
 Scanner usersel = new Scanner(System.in);
 String selvar = usersel.nextLine();
 if (selvar.equals("Об игре")) {
  System.out.println("Бла бла бла");
 } else {
  System.out.println("Что-то не так!");
 }
```

Данный код пишет в консоль "Что-то не так!", хотя я пишу в строчку сканера слова "Об игре". Когда я пишу условие `if (selvar.equals("Test"))` всё работает, но с русскими буквами нет. В чём ошибка?

Comment: Ввожу то я как раз то, еще и с большой буквы. Хорошо, попробую вставить.

Comment: Скорее всего, проблема с кодировкой русский букв: Java по умолчанию ожидает одну, а используется другая (какая именно — зависит от ОС и способа запуска). См, например, [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/394010/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%b2-java).

Comment: Возможно еще есть проблема во фразе "Об игре", возможно и там опечатка, например `О` - английская буква. Попробуйте заново написать эту строку в условии.

Comment: ДА! Когда я пишу условие if (selvar.equals("Test")) всё работает, но с русскими буквами нет. Как сканеру кодировку настроить?

Comment: При создании, в конструкторе: `new Scanner(Источник, Кодировка)`.

Comment: 1) Также можете попробовать использовать метод Scanner.useLocale(Locale locale). 2) Если работаете не в IDE, а в консоли, то могут быть и проблемы с кодировкой. Посмотрите здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/696843/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-java-java-util-scanner